# Error when installing python3 packages in Virtualenv using pip

Tags: python, pip, ubuntu-14.04, python-packaging

i am trying install pytrend (included some packages eg: numpy , pandas, ... ) in my virtual environment, after activating the venv and running

```
pip install pytrends
```

the command line troughs this error :

```
> Command /root/environments/my_env/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools,
> tokenize;__file__='/root/environments/my_env/build/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize,
> 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__,
> 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-ibvjaren-record/install-record.txt
> --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /root/environments/my_env/include/site/python3.4 failed with error
> code 1 in /root/environments/my_env/build/lxml Storing debug log for
> failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

i am using python3.4 and ubuntu 14.04, did I missed something?

**Edit 1:** here is /root/.pip/pip.log contents

```
> Cleaning up...   Removing temporary dir
> /root/environments/my_env/build... Command
> /root/environments/my_env/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools,
> tokenize;__file__='/root/environments/my_env/build/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr($
> Exception information: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/root/environments/my_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py",
> line 122, in main
>     status = self.run(options, args)   File "/root/environments/my_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py",
> line 283, in run
>     requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)   File
> "/root/environments/my_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/req.py",
> line 1436, in install
>     requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)   File "/root/environments/my_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/req.py",
> line 707, in install
>     cwd=self.source_dir, filter_stdout=self._filter_install, show_stdout=False)   File
> "/root/environments/my_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/util.py",
> line 715, in call_subprocess
>     % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd)) pip.exceptions.InstallationError: Command
> /root/environments/my_env/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools,
> tokenize;__file__='/root/environments/my_env/build/lx$
```

**PS :**
I rebuilt the Vps OS, but this issue not solved yet.

Comment: if he is in the virtualenv when doing 'pip install pytrends' then there is no difference between pip and pip3 as they both use the python version of the virtual environment

Comment: I think it's Gcc compiler issue, isn't it?

Comment: It's hard to tell from just that log, but a quick guess would be you're missing lxml headers, which seem to be required. You can try to `apt-get install libxml2-dev` and restart the install

Comment: @spectras not working again

Comment: If you never install packages needing compilation, you might be missing the whole tool chain, so you can try to `apt-get install build-essential python-dev python3-dev`. Then, you'll need to re-create your virtualenv for the newly installed `python-dev` bits to be included in it. If it still fails, with another error, please update the question at that point.

Comment: @spectras as  i setup like this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-python-3-and-set-up-a-local-programming-environment-on-ubuntu-16-04   
 it is what i get : build-essential is already the newest version.
python-dev is already the newest version.
python3-dev is already the newest version.
python3-dev set to manually installed.

Comment: I don't understand what's going wrong. The tutorial you pointed is good. On your latest tries, is the error still exactly the same? If you manually `pip install lxml`, do you get the same error?

Comment: @spectras no , i installed lxml and numpy by pip with no errors but for pytrends got this error

Comment: show us the list of packages that pip downloaded when you executed 'pip install pytrends'. There should be about a dozen.

Comment: @DavidJenkins does it have any direct command ?

Comment: whenever you use pip to install packages, there is output following showing the packages that are being downloaded and installed. It may be nothing, but I am curious what else pip is trying to install.

Comment: @DavidJenkins I uploaded pip output here , thanks . https://www.dropbox.com/s/7db0fe1n6rf75c3/log.txt?dl=0

Comment: OK. I think I found the error in the following output:

Downloading lxml-3.8.0.tar.gz (3.8MB): 3.8MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/lxml/setup.py) egg_info for package lxml
    Building lxml version 3.8.0.
    Building without Cython.
    ERROR: b'/bin/sh: 1: xslt-config: not found\n'
    ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **

it looks like lxml is not being built

Comment: Perhaps it also needs `libxslt1-dev` package installed?

Comment: @DavidJenkins  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement  for both packages you mentioned

Comment: @spectras  what is wrong with this OS ? https://www.dropbox.com/s/5jum3qqrbxcv7ft/Capture.PNG?dl=0

Comment: Can you install `libxslt1-dev` and retry the pip install again? That should solve the `xslt-config not found`

Comment: @AliRezaNouri> oh, I meant using `apt-get install libxslt1-dev`. That's a system package, not a python package. It's used by the python module to interface with native code.

Comment: execute the following: apt list --installed | egrep 'xslt|libxml'. pip install pytrends installed successfully for and I have the following packages installed: libxml, libxml2, libxml2-utils, libxslt1, python-libxml2

Comment: @spectras I was thinking the same thing. Appears a lot of dev packages are not installed.

Comment: @DavidJenkins it works and installed successfully , i dont know why but thanks :)

Comment: @spectras special thanks to you bro :)

Comment: Well good luck with your python project, see you around on another question should you have some while working on it. And don't devalue yourself like you did earlier, your question was clear, included the full error and you reacted swiftly on requests for more info; by SO newcomers standards you're doing great.

Comment: @spectras thanks dude